# How to discover all static fields of a certain type within a UITypeEditor?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

I want people who use my custom control to choose a constant with a simple dropdown. The control should be reusable and therefor resides in a library so it can't access an enum, and the constants could in fact be defined anywhere.

Problem is that AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() does not contain the current project you are designing in. And when I create a separate project it sometimes works but mostly it doesn't. And with doesn't work I mean: It can't find any classes/constants defined in the library, so they don't show up in the dropdown.

Everything else already works. The dropdown works. Code generation is a but clunky but it works. And I can always find constants defined in TestControl itself.

It seems like the designer itself doesn't always load all the assemblies/projects which are available. So how can I load the project which I need within the context of the designer/visual studio itself? Or how do I reference/find other projects within my list of dependencies from within the UITypeEditor?

I have created my own TestControl:

```cs
public partial class TestControl : UserControl, IHasTags
{
    public static readonly ITestItem A = new TestItemImpl(null, "A", "Aap");
    public static readonly ITestItem B = new TestItemImpl(null, "B", "B");
    public static readonly ITestItem C_xx = new TestItemImpl(null, "C", "C");
    public static readonly ITestItem D = new TestItemImpl(null, "D", "D");

    [Editor(typeof(ItemEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public ITestItem item { get; set; }

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

With my own editor:

```cs
public class ItemEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private IWindowsFormsEditorService _editorService;

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // drop down mode (we'll host a listbox in the drop down)
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        _editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        // use a list box
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        lb.SelectedValueChanged += OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged;
        lb.Width = 300;

        // get the analytic object from context
        // this is how we get the list of possible benchmarks
        TestControl ctrl = (TestControl)context.Instance;


        // Add all test items
        IList<StaticFieldInfo<ITestItem>> items = ClassHelper.getStaticFields<IHasTags, ITestItem>();
        foreach (StaticFieldInfo<ITestItem> item in items)
        {
            lb.Items.Add(item);
        }

        // show this model stuff
        _editorService.DropDownControl(lb);
        if (lb.SelectedItem == null) // no selection, return the passed-in value as is
            return value;

        StaticFieldInfo<ITestItem> result = (StaticFieldInfo<ITestItem>)lb.SelectedItem;

        return result.value;
    }


    private void OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // close the drop down as soon as something is clicked
        _editorService.CloseDropDown();
    }
}
```

And I collect all constants with the following helper:

```cs
public class StaticFieldInfo<T>
{
    public StaticFieldInfo(FieldInfo fieldInfo, T value)
    {
        this.fieldInfo = fieldInfo;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public T value { get; private set; }
    public FieldInfo fieldInfo { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString() + " (" + fieldInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + fieldInfo.Name + ")";
    }
}

public class ClassHelper
{
    public static IList<StaticFieldInfo<T>> getStaticFields<C, T>()
    {
        Type classType = typeof(C);
        Type fieldType = typeof(T);
        List<StaticFieldInfo<T>> result = new List<StaticFieldInfo<T>>();

        foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Type t in asm.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (classType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
                    {
                        foreach (FieldInfo f in t.GetFields())
                        {
                            if (f.IsStatic && fieldType.IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
                            {
                                T value = (T)f.GetValue(null);
                                if (value != null)
                                {
                                    result.Add(new StaticFieldInfo<T>(f, value));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
                // Ignore errors
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

The rest of the code (less important):

```cs
public interface IHasTags
{
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ITestItemConverter))]
public interface ITestItem
{
    string driver { get; set; }
    string tag { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}


public class ITestItemConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        // we only know how to convert from to a string
        return typeof(string) == destinationType;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {


        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }

        return "(none)";
    }
}

[DesignerSerializer(typeof(ItemSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]
public class TestItemImpl : ITestItem
{
    public TestItemImpl()
    {
    }

    public TestItemImpl(string driver, string tag, string name)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public string driver { get; set; }

    public string tag { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSerializer : CodeDomSerializer
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object codeObject)
    {


        // This is how we associate the component with the serializer.
        CodeDomSerializer baseClassSerializer = (CodeDomSerializer)manager.
        GetSerializer(typeof(TestItemImpl).BaseType, typeof(CodeDomSerializer));

        /* This is the simplest case, in which the class just calls the base class
            to do the work. */
        return baseClassSerializer.Deserialize(manager, codeObject);
    }

    public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object value)
    {
        /* Associate the component with the serializer in the same manner as with
            Deserialize */
        CodeDomSerializer baseClassSerializer = (CodeDomSerializer)manager.
            GetSerializer(typeof(TestItemImpl).BaseType, typeof(CodeDomSerializer));


        object codeObject = baseClassSerializer.Serialize(manager, value);



        /* Anything could be in the codeObject.  This sample operates on a
            CodeStatementCollection. */
        if (codeObject is CodeStatementCollection)
        {
            CodeStatementCollection statements = (CodeStatementCollection)codeObject;

            StaticFieldInfo<ITestItem> field = null;
            foreach (StaticFieldInfo<ITestItem> item in ClassHelper.getStaticFields<IHasTags, ITestItem>())
            {
                if (value == item.value)
                {
                    field = item;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If field can be found (should be always)
            if (field != null)
            {
                statements = new CodeStatementCollection();
                statements.Add(new CodeSnippetExpression(typeof(ITestItem).FullName + "  " + this.GetUniqueName(manager, value) + " = " + typeof(TestControl).FullName + "." + field.fieldInfo.Name));

                codeObject = statements;
            }
        }
        return codeObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: You already know the type of the object, it is context.Instance.GetType().  No point in trying to find it back the hard way, just pass it to your getStaticFields() method.

Comment: That's not what I need. I want all constants everywhere. Not just from one type.

Comment: That's pretty ... unusual.  Type.Assembly then.  Beyond that, searching the entire disk for all assemblies gets to be rather unpractical.

Comment: Just within the project for which you are designing a component or form, and then all its dependencies. Not the entire disk.

Comment: You are overlooking a giant ostrich-and-egg problem.  Your UITypeEditor is used at design time.  *Before* the project is built.  You don't have any assemblies to reflect on until *after* it is built.